# php preg_replace find &mdash; replace with —

Tags: php, regex

I'm guessing that the & and ; are messing up my search. When I search for just mdash it finds it but of course doesn't replace the & or ; surrounding it.

This is what I've tried that I think should work (I've tried a bunch of other things too, but...):

```
$description = "there. &mdash; with David";
$description = preg_replace("/\&mdash\;/", "—", $description);
```

I've googled and searched SO to no avail, so now I'm just pulling my hair out...

Thanks!

added:

I'm getting $description from the url: ?description=clay%252520%252526mdash%25253B%252520with%252520Veronica

```
$description = $_GET["description"];
$description=rawurldecode($description);
$description=rawurldecode($description);
$description=htmlentities($description);
$description=stripslashes($description);
$description = preg_replace("/\&mdash\;/", "—", $description);
echo $decription;
```

produces:
clay & mdash; with Veronica 
(without the ' ' between & mdash) since it's converting to an mdash here

Comment: That should work fine, just tried in the terminal real quick.

Comment: str_repalce() would be faster

Comment: @Dagon That's where I started, $message = str_replace("&mdash;", "—", $message);,it's not working either.

Comment: http://codepad.org/iAEHm8DA works for me

Comment: must be my input then, hmmm editing question...

Comment: the `&`is not actully `&amp;` by any chance?

Comment: @Dagon I've echoed the $description out between code and pre tags and it shows it as &mdash; but isn't converting that onscreen to an mdash like I expected it to either.  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: http://codepad.org/J3lKGLLB hows that ?

Comment: @Dagon I tried this anyway, and it worked!  Thanks!
$description = preg_replace("/\&amp\;mdash\;/i", "—", $description);

Comment: @Dagon put the &amp; into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your & is actully the html entitie `&amp;` so you need to replace that

```
$description =str_replace("&amp;mdash;", "—", $description);
```

[html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is another approach

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `preg_replace` to replace a constant string. Just use `str_replace` instead.

```
$description = str_replace("&mdash;","—", $description);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  tim@roflcopter /tmp $ cat >blah.php
  <?php
  $description = "there. &MDASH; with David";
  $description = preg_replace("/\&mdash\;/i", "—", $description);
  echo $description;

  tim@roflcopter /tmp $ php blah.php
  there. — with David
```

It looks like it works, however if you are going to use preg_replace, you might want to do a case-insensitive replace... this might be your problem with search breaking.